# Where did org.springframework.security.ui.AbstractProcessing Filter go?

Tags: spring-security, spring-webflow

I'm migrating a legacy application from Spring Security 2.x to 3.x. When my .jsp's are deployed I get the following errors:

14:49:01,333 ERROR [org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.[jboss.web].[localhost].[/tic].[jsp]] Servlet.service() for servlet jsp threw exception: org.apache.jasper.JasperException: Unable to compile class for JSP:

An error occurred at line: 6 in the generated java file
Only a type can be imported. org.springframework.security.ui.AbstractProcessing Filter resolves to a package

An error occurred at line: 7 in the generated java file
Only a type can be imported. org.springframework.security.ui.webapp.Authenticat ionProcessingFilter resolves to a package

An error occurred at line: 8 in the generated java file
Only a type can be imported. org.springframework.security.AuthenticationExcepti on resolves to a package

In the .jsp in question, I have the following:

The problem is that these classes no longer exist in 3.0. So, my question is, where did they go, or is there a better way to do these things in 3.0?

Comment: Are you looking for [this](http://static.springsource.org/spring-security/site/docs/3.0.x/apidocs/org/springframework/security/web/authentication/AbstractProcessingFilter.html) class? It's deprecated, have a look.

Answer (score 2):

**In Spring 3.x**

For error line: 6 & 7:

`org.springframework.security.ui.AbstractProcessingFilter`
**TO**
 `org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AbstractProcessingFilter`. 
However, its deprecated. So use this 
 `org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter` [javadoc](http://static.springsource.org/spring-security/site/docs/3.0.x/apidocs/org/springframework/security/web/authentication/AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.html)

For error line: 8

`org.springframework.security.AuthenticationException`
**TO**
`org.springframework.security.core.AuthenticationException`  [javadoc](http://static.springsource.org/spring-security/site/docs/3.0.x/apidocs/org/springframework/security/core/AuthenticationException.html)

I hope this helps!